# Hiding HTML tag in webbrowser

Tags: c#, html, browser

I want to hide an HTML tag in my web browser.The problem that I have is the fact that I must not use javascript.
I have come up with this block of code:

```
    public void HideHTMLTag(string ControlID)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement HTMLControl = doc.GetElementById(ControlID);
        HTMLControl.Style = "'display: none;'";                  
        webBrowser1.Refresh();
    }
```

I call this in a button event.I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this the code used in Asp.Net application right.?

Comment: @AkshayJoy:No it is in C# winform.

Comment: So are you displaying HTML in your WinForm? More details will help. Also I assume the block of code you have does not work? What does it do now?

Comment: @canhazbits:Exatcly.I have an HTML page which is shown in a webbrowser.I want to hide some specific tags of it by using this function.I mean,I want some tags not to be shown some times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code in documentCompleted event..
URL:- [Hiding HTML tag in webbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382036/hiding-html-tag-in-webbrowser)

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement HTMLControl = doc.GetElementById("question-header");
            //HTMLControl.Style = "'display: none;'";
            if (HTMLControl != null)
            {
                HTMLControl.Style = "display: none";
            }
        }
```